# Trouble sharing files from one PC to another through Ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, network-shares, file-sharing

So what I am trying to do is to share files from one PC to another one by connecting an Ethernet (RJ45) cable to both of the computers. In order to do this I am following this guide: http://www.tufitech.com/how-to/fastest-way-to-transfer-files-from-pc-to-pc/

The problem is that the PC 1 is not showing up in my Network folder on PC 2 and I am stuck here, therefore I would appreciate all tips and ideas of what could be wrong. Both of the computers are running Windows 7.

I have disabled password protected sharing and tried different IP-settings based on the linked guide. I am also sharing a test-folder that is set to Read and Write with "Everyone". I must be missing something, or there is something additional that I have to do.

Network configuration (IPv4):

PC 1:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.20
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.21
```

PC 2:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.21
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.20
```

Comment: Are you sure you using crossover Ethernet cable? Try access another computer directly (use \\ip.ip.ip.ip) of another computer instead of waiting when it appears in network (for Windows it can legally take up to 12 minutes)

Comment: Write network configuration on both PC, post output of `ipconfig -all` command. Can you ping PC1 from PC2?

Comment: @Alex Most (all?) current devices have have implemented ethernet auto mdix. Why do I still need need crossover cable?

Comment: @Eri. mdix would work with switches, I never saw that two computers (recent ones that support mdix) can figure out where is  Rx or Tx if they connected directly

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.1.21 from PC1?

Comment: @Alex is there a way to make it figure out?

Comment: "Most (all?) current devices"  So, are you using current network adapters?  Are the adapters you're using auto-sensing ports on those adapters?   "is there a way to make it figure out?"  Yes, use a cross-over cable.  You need to do some basic troubleshooting, so to start (as you've been asked twice now by Adam): **Can you ping the machines from each other by IP address?**

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am not able to do it now since I am off-location atm. Will try it within a few hours. Thanks for all the help so far all! Should it be possible to ping even though I am not using crossover? (I will try to get this cable asap).

Comment: @Eri. If you can ping then just try to access another comp  in navigation bar of explorer as I showed above, by IP.

Comment: I could ping and reach it trough the IP, everything is working fine, the problem was that the PC was not showing up in the network. A crossover cable was not needed. Thanks all for the help! Much appreciated!